# notation of Path to files/folders/drives that is shared on a network in windows?

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

When some thing shared on network using windows network share option. Some people use path like `\\something\something\something$` I'm don't know if this is correct way or not. but as far as I remember there is a dollar sign. Can any one please tell me.

1. What is this notation?
2. Where can I find more details about this?
3. What is `samba` server/sharing? I don't understand when people use it. Is it something related to Linux?

**EDIT**

I'm a programmer. I guess this file sharing on network using windows uses client server architecture. I want to know what is this server on windows called? What protocol does it use? client is of course our windows explorer.exe? Which service in services.msc is responsible for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know,

$ sign is for to create a hidden share by adding a dollar sign ('$') to the end of the share name. A hidden share doesn't appear in My Network Places or Network Neighborhood on any of the networked computers. In order to access a hidden share you need to already know the name of it.

you can even see here for detail facts

- http://www.practicallynetworked.com/sharing/xp/filesharing.htm
- http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2007/04/25/what-do-those-dollar-signs-on-shares-do.aspx

From [Samba.org](http://www.samba.org/samba/what_is_samba.html):

> Samba is software that can be run on a
>   platform other than Microsoft Windows,
>   for example, UNIX, Linux, IBM System
>   390, OpenVMS, and other operating
>   systems. Samba uses the TCP/IP
>   protocol that is installed on the host
>   server. When correctly configured, it
>   allows that host to interact with a
>   Microsoft Windows client or server as
>   if it is a Windows file and print
>   server.

Of course, it's related to Linux :)

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29)

Comment: your `$` explanation is correct, but it doesn't match the example in the question.  remember that path breaks down into `\\server\sharename\path\to\some\folder\or\file`.  an "invisible" share would look like `\\server\youcantseethis$\path\to\some\folder`.  the `$` is part of the share name, not part of the path.  (the OP may have misremembered the format, so i blame the example, not your explanation.)

Comment: @quack You are right. I didn't know about it. So, I wrote what ever I remembered hoping for correction.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention), the notation is called *Universal Naming Convention* or *Uniform Naming Convention*. [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file) seems to use the first at least.